# Dart CheckboxInputElement doesn't show text

Tags: dart

Dart CheckboxInputElement adds specified text between opening and ending input tags and the browser ignores this text. For example, the following dart code:

```
  FormElement form = new FormElement();
  CheckboxInputElement option = new CheckboxInputElement();
  option.name = "text1";
  option.value = "text1";
  option.text = "text1";
  form.children.add(option);
  window.children.add(form);
```

creates the following html code:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="text1" value"text1">text1</input>
</form>
```

I end up with checkboxes without descriptors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a Label with the descriptor text and link it to the Checkbox:

```dart
FormElement form = new FormElement();
CheckboxInputElement option = new CheckboxInputElement();
option.name = "text1";
option.value = "text1";
option.id = "text1";
form.children.add(option);      
LabelElement label = new LabelElement();
label.htmlFor = 'text1';
label.text = "This is a checkbox label";
form.children.add(label);
window.children.add(form);
```

The for property will look for the input with the id specified and connect them (so that clicking on the label text will toggle the checkbox) .

You will end up with the following HTML:

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="text1" id="text1">
  <label for="text1">This is a checkbox label</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I thought a descriptor can be added without using a label element. Anyhow, thank you for your suggestion. It does the trick.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that "htmlFor" ties the label to the checkbox element.